# How to compute summary statistics and quantiles of user defined discrete distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, discrete

I am interested to find out the mean, median, Variance, Skewness, Kurtosis and Quantiles of the following discrete distribution with pmf (E^((1 - E^[Nu]) n) [Nu]^x BellB[n, x])/x! with x=0,1,2......
please guide me how I compute these measures using methematica? share mathematica code.
Reg;
Amin

Comment: `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[(E^((1 - E^Nu) n) Nu^x BellB[n, x])/x!, {x, 0, Infinity, 1}];` then `Mean[dist]`, `Variance[dist]` ... etc. However these won't work unless you provide a value for Nu and n. If Nu=1 and n=1, then `Sum[(E^((1 - E^Nu) n) Nu^x BellB[n, x])/x!, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]` is `E^(2 - E)`, so there's some normalization in n and Nu required.

Comment: You can get a symbolic result by setting a positive integer value for `n` and use `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[(E^((1 - E^Nu) n) Nu^x BellB[n, x])/x! /. n -> 5, {x, 0, Infinity, 1}, Method -> "Normalize"]; Mean[dist]//FullSimplify` (as an example for `n = 5`.  By trying different values of `n` you might see a general formula for any positive integer value of `n`.

Comment: Dear JimB thanks for response. Actually I want to compute these measures in symbolic form i.e. with n and Nu

Comment: What makes you think there is a compact symbolic form for even the mean?

Comment: Yes in compact symbolic form especially for Mean, Variance, and Quantile

Comment: @MuhammadAmin It is unlikely that a compact symbolic form exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dist = ProbabilityDistribution[(E^((1 - E^Nu) n) Nu^x BellB[n, x])/x!, {x, 0, 
    Infinity, 1},
   Assumptions -> {Element[n, Integers], n >= 0},
   Method -> "Normalize"];
```

Verifying that the distribution is valid for some typical values of `n`

```
And @@ Table[
  Sum[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, Infinity}] == 1, {n, 0, 5}]

(* True *)
```

For a specific value of `n`

```
n = 3;

Join[
  {{Style[StringForm["n = ``", n], 14, Bold], SpanFromLeft}},
  {#, #[dist]} & /@ {Mean, Variance, Skewness, Kurtosis}] //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

The median and other quartiles cannot be found symbolically.

Comment: Dear Bob thanks for your response